# LUA patterns to detect matching date

Tags: date, duplicates, lua-patterns

I struggling to find the correct LUA code to detect if two dates appear after each other.

I have something similar which detects two keywords, but it's not working on my dates.

Here's the LUA code I have so far:

```
(%a+) %- %1$
```

Cheers,

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to match? Also, what language are you working in?

Comment: Please provide some examples of the text you are checking and the expected result.

Comment: It seems you want to match repeat the same pattern with `%1` - no, this `%1` matches the same alpha characters matched with `(%a+)`. Try removing `$` end of string anchor. Please provide sample strings you are trying to match. BTW, what you are using is not regex, these are Lua patterns.

Comment: I absolutely wouldn't use regex for this. It will be hard to get right, especially if it's possible for a date to be duplicated more than once. What tools/languages do you have at your disposal?

Comment: Thanks all, sure, here's what I'm trying to match:

Comment: 2017-03-15 - 2017-03-15

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/1F1L9s, try `'^(%d+%-%d+%-%d+) %- %1$'` or `'(%d+%-%d+%-%d+) %- %1'` (if you want to match shorter substrings inside a longer string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main trouble here is that you want to match a date like `2017-03-19` with `%a+` pattern. `%a` matches a letter, `%a+` matches 1 or more letters.

You need to replace this pattern with a more precise one, like `%d+%-%d+%-%d+` or `%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%d`:

```
'(%d+%-%d+%-%d+) %- %1'
```

where `%d` matches a digit.

Now, if you want to match a whole string like this, you need to enclose the pattern with `^` and `$` anchors.

```
'^(%d+%-%d+%-%d+) %- %1$'
```

If you want to add word boundaries,

```
 '%f[%d](%d+%-%d+%-%d+) %- %1%f[%D]'
```